# Crankshaft timing belt

Tags: timing, belt, water, pump

I’ve been trying to loosen my crank shaft pulley to get to my timing belt and water pump. Well I couldn’t find a tool to do it with so I got a air impact and didn’t think it was working and it turned crank shaft pulley counter clockwise so I did a full turn with wrench to get it back to zero     But when I did it out the top two pulleys at half a turn and I did the crank shaft a full turn.  So not thinking I turned it another full turn and everything was back in line. But then I panicked and turned it counter clockwise all the way back to where i first started. I basically just wanna know how screwed I am?

Comment: Never turn the engine backwards when servicing the tbelt.

Answer (score 2):

The camshaft pulleys are meant to turn at half engine speed as the 4 stroke cycle needs two revolutions of the crankshaft but the valves open once per cycle.

As long as the belt did not slip you should be ok.

However I suggest that you only ever turn the engine in the direction of rotation  - a habit I stick to.

Comment: Thank you that makes me feel better all my marks still line up so I don’t think that it slipped